# open 2nd python console to probe run-time variable?

Tags: python, debugging, runtime, inspect

Python infinite loop code below:

```
i = 0
while True:
    i = i + 1
```

I know I can use `import IPython; IPython.embed(`) or `import pdb; pdb.set_trace()` 
to pause loop running and get value of i --- run-time debug.

however, what I want is if I can "tapping" into this loop on demand probe value without pause it, similar to sniffer packets in network area?

PS: not as simple as `print i` to terminal directly.

Thanks.

Comment: @Lattyware Thank you very much, pyringe is really something cool.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Pyringe](https://github.com/google/pyringe) will do what you want.

Just grab it and run `python -m pyringe`, then you should be able to inject it in and debug like you wanted.